# Windows 8: How do I get an error message or log of failed wifi connection?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking

Occasionally, I'll try to connect to Wifi and it'll give me the "Checking Network Requirements" screen, then finally end with a "Cannot Connect" message and an offer to use a useless troubleshooting tool:

[image: Windows Cannot Connect message]

This gives me essentially *no* information about the problem - could be the signal is bad, could be an authentication problem, could be anything. Is there a way to get an actually informative error message from this, or, even better, a log of what's happening?

I tried their diagnostic tool, and it basically just chugs away for a bit and says, "Hey, did you know your wifi is broken?"

**Edit**: I did see the [similar question on Windows 7 Logs](https://superuser.com/questions/334483/where-are-windows-7-wireless-connection-event-logs), but when I went to Events Viewer, Applications and Services Log did not populate and gave no indication of loading (so I thought that the logs had moved or something). Eventually it did populate and the logs turned out to be in Microsoft > Windows > WLAN-AutoConfig.

Comment: Welcome to Windows wireless networking, I had similar issue in W7, network troubleshooter was of no use and never actually told me what issue it was running into, poor diagnostics imho, wound up changing the wifi radio channel in the router and that solved it.

Comment: One place to start is the Event Viewer (where Windows logs things) under "Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Diagnostics-Networking".

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, I did see that, but I didn't think I had any logs in there. It gave no indication it was loading anything, but when I left it open for a while it eventually populated the dialog. This can be closed as dupe or you can convert your comment to an answer and I'll accept. The relevant log seems to be Applications and Services Logs>Microsoft>Windows>WLAN-Autoconfig.