# How can I check WiFi connection order in Windows 10?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I found a useful answer on here about [setting the WiFi connection order in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/994982/how-can-i-set-wifi-connection-order-in-windows-10). Essentially you use this command:

```
netsh wlan set profileorder name="connectionname" interface="Wi-Fi" priority=1
```

But is there a way to verify that the command has taken effect? I still find that my wireless switches to a non-preferred network occasionally, even though I set the right one to priority 1 and the wrong one to priority 10.

EDIT: Or alternatively, is there a way to check why it sometimes changes network, like a log of some kind?

EDIT 2 - Thanks Moab for your comment - the Event log in that link is very useful. But I'd still like to know about checking the network priority if possible!

```
Event Viewer/Applications and Services logs/Microsoft/Windows/WLAN-Autoconfig
```

Comment: see this for logs...http://superuser.com/questions/334483/where-are-windows-7-wireless-connection-event-logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, we can now see preference order via the GUI. Not sure when this option became available but it's working for me in Windows 10 v1809.

1. Open Settings.
2. Click on Network & Security.
3. Click on Wi-Fi.
4. Click the Manage known networks link.

I can't see a way to manage the order in the GUI, but if I run the following command I can force my hotspot to move to the bottom of the list. You can see in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiWUi.png) that they are organised by preference.

```
netsh wlan set profileorder name="GalaxyHotspot" interface="WiFi" priority=4
```